# Rotational Hamiltonian for collective model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

The effect of rotation can be considered by modelling the nucleus as a rotating body, characterised by some moment of inertia. Then how The Hamiltonian describing rotation is?

> $$H_{rot}=\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\Im}R^{2}$$

where:

$R$    is     the rotational angular momentum, and
   $\Im$      is     the moment of inertia.

Assuming all the angular momentum is associated with collective rotation, the rotational eigenenergies are then
How this can be written, 
$$E_{rot}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2\Im}I(I+1)$$
where:

$I$ is     the total angular momentum.

Source: [Rotational Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aANUnuclearhonoursclass/Nuclear_Rotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression is classical. To quantize it, you can use the fact that the eigenvalues of $R^2$ are of the form $I(I+1)$. The fact that it's $I(I+1)$ rather than $I^2$ means we're adding $I$ to it; this is the first-order quantum-mechanical correction to the classical energy. The ultimate justification for this is simply that it works, in the sense that for nuclei with large, static, axially symmetric deformations, we do observe rotational bands with, at least approximately, an $I(I+1)$ energy spectrum (assuming it's an even-even nucleus and the band has $K=0$). These bands are observed only for rotation about an axis perpendicular to the symmetry axis. The moment of inertia $\mathscr{I}$ is always observed (except possibly at very high spins) to be significantly less than the value for a rigid rotor, and this is interpreted as being due to the fact that the nucleus has pairing correlations that make it analogous to a superfluid.